# MovingSum of list of integers

Tags: python, array-algorithms

I want to calculate the moving sum of a list of integers with a window of size 3.  I have a class as such:

```
class MovingSum:
    def __init__(self, window=3):
       self.window = window
    
    def push(self, nums: List[int]):
       pass

    def belongs(self, total) -> bool:
       pass
```

I need to calculate the moving sum of 3 numbers and keep track of total.  Example:
Movingsum.push([1, 2, 3, 4]) will calculate the sum of (1, 2, 3) and 4, hence it keeps two totals, which is 6 and 4.  Then next calls to Movingsum.push([10]) will update the total and hence we have the folloing totals: 6 and 14.  Then Movingsum.push([20]) will update the total and hence we have 6 and 34.  Now, Next call to Movingsum.push([10, 20, 30]) will hence have 3 totals calculated: 6, 34 and 60 etc.  Hence i need to keep track of the running totals.  I'm having trouble updating the total i have already calculated.

My attempt:

```
def __init__(self, window=3):
   self.window = window
   self.totals = set()
   self.count = 0

def push(self, nums: List[int]):
    total = 0
    for num in nums:
        total += num
        self.count += 1
        if self.count % 3 == 0:
           self.totals.add(total)
           self.count = 0

def belongs(self, total) -> bool:
    return total in self.totals
```

where the belongs function needs to check if the total has already been calculated.  I'm having trouble figuring out how to update the new totals.  Thanks

Moving sum needs to be calculated for 3 numbers before moving to next 3 etc
test case:
Start:

```
nums = [1, 2]
MovingSum.push(nums)
Now total is 3

MovingSum.push([10, 20])
```

Now total is 13 and 20 (since on first push, we calculated total of two numbers which had value 3, but we need total of 3 numbers.  Hence update total to 3 + 10 (which has 3 numbers), and since only one number remaining, we have two totals: 13 and 20

```
MovingSum.push([40])
```

update the total: 13, 60 (since total of 20 has only one number)

```
MovingSum.push([100, 20, 30])
```

Update the total: 13, 160, 50 (3rd total is 20 + 30 which is two numbers)

```
MovingSum.push([40, 100])
```

Update the total: 13, 160, 90, 100 (since 90 is sum of 20 + 30 + 40) and we have one number remaining which is 100.

Comment: Hi, could you elaborate on the expected functionality? Its not clear with the current example you have mentioned. If you can add a few test cases (inputs, expected outputs and step by step explanation) that would really help

Comment: k i added new test cases

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you have a constant stream of numbers coming in, and you want the total of each n-item window (which I'll call a group) within that. So, you'll need a list of totals of all the groups so far, and you'll need to keep track of the running total of the items within the current (partial) group, as well as the number in the partial group.

The code below achieves this -- I'm sure it could be cleaner using features from `itertools` and the like, but I've tried to keep it simple so you can see what's going on.

```
class MovingSum:

    window_size: int
    totals: list[int]
    count: int

    def __init__(self, window_size: int = 3):
        self.window_size = window_size
        self.totals = []
        self.count = 0

    def push(self, nums: list[int]) -> None:
        offset = 0

        # Handle partial set as a special case, since the final total
        # needs incrementing rather than a new total being added.
        if self.count > 0:
            items = nums[:self.window_size - self.count]
            offset = len(items)
            self.totals[-1] += sum(items)
            self.count = (self.count + offset) % self.window_size

        # Iterate over the remaining items, and stop once we run out.
        # Whilst we have full groups, self.count will remain 0, but
        # the final group may be partial so we recalculate it each loop.
        while offset < len(nums):
            items = nums[offset:offset + self.window_size]
            self.totals.append(sum(items))
            self.count = len(items) % self.window_size
            offset += self.window_size

    def belongs(self, total: int) -> bool:
        if self.count > 0:
            return total in self.totals[:-1]
        else:
            return total in self.totals
```

The `belongs()` function above also excludes partial totals from the membership check, but your simpler version will work fine if you don't need this extra complication.

As an aside, your `belongs()` function will get quite slow as `totals` gets large. This won't be an issue for a few hundred items, but if you're in the tens of thousands or more than a `set()` is a much more efficient way of checking for membership -- it will also handle de-duplication rather conveniently.

Comment: yea this was an interview question for me which i failed.  So wanted to understand the correct way to do this so that i dont repeat the same mistake.

Comment: can't you just use a set for self.totals instead of list since checking if total has been calculated can be O(n)? but yea i think this looks correct.  can you give me a suggestion how to get good in algorithms like this?

Comment: If you just build a `set` within `belongs()`, it's O(n) anyway to build the set -- you'd need to do it as you go along to amortise the cost. Also, as with just about every programming challenge, there isn't a "correct" solution — just different tradeoffs in performance and readability. In terms of improving, try to minimise special cases, come up with a step that can be looped and will be the same every time. My code above has that one special case for partial groups which I find unpleasant -- perhaps could be avoided if I thought about it more.

Comment: Other than that, I can only suggest practice, practice, practice. Use sites like TopCoder, Coderbyte, Project Euler, HackerRank, etc. You'll learn an awful lot if you look at how other people solve the problems -- again, look for ways people avoid special cases and keep code clean and repeatable. Generally the good solutions will often be the shorter ones (although this isn't 100% true!). Once you get good at breaking the problem down into simple pieces in your head, implementing those pieces becomes straightforward.

Comment: Thanks a lot Cartroo.  im turning 39 and i want to become an excellent engineer.  When i saw your code i was in awe but also got very sad as i realized there are levels to this game.  Im going to use your suggestions and become very good.

Comment: It’s great that you want to improve yourself — no matter how good you get, it’s always important to keep trying to improve! Trust me, there will always be people who can code better or faster — but that’s ok, everyone has other skills they can bring to their role as well. Building things right is important, but it’s more important to build the right things. Knowing how to structure code to solve a problem is always an important skill, but while talent plays a role it can be learned and practiced like any skill. Put in the hours and you’ll get results.